# How do I configure PHP for sendmail if I am not the server admin?

Tags: php, hosting, sendmail

I am designing a website for a company that uses a Windows hosting platform through Peer1 Hosting. I am trying to get a php contact form (that works correctly on a linux server) to work properly. I had Peer1 install php on the server but the emails are still not being sent (there is no error but the emails are not being delivered).

From what I understand, the SMTP sendmail functions need to be configured in the php.ini but I don't believe this is something I have access to and Peer1 won't offer support for php because it is an unsupported installation. Please help!

EDIT: I am trying this as a small test... I am not sure about the 'smpt.domain.com' because some things say it should be 'mail.domain.com' or just the server name but I only have an IP address.

```
<?php
ini_set('SMTP', 'smtp.domain.com');
ini_set('smtp_port', '25');
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'example@domain.com');

if(mail('me@gmail.com','TEST CONTACT FORM','TEST MESSAGE')){
      echo('ok');
    }
else{
      echo('not ok');
    }
?>
```

This is the error I received when adding error reporting:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.theinspros.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\HTTP\Old Web\version.php on line 9

Comment: I don't think sendmail will be installed by default windows. Also this is more of a sever question. You may have better luck on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: What did you try?  Did you try placing the needed settings in a local `php.ini`?  Did you try PHP's SMTP functions?

Comment: @JasonK:  serverfault.com is reserved for sysadmins and requires the person to have access to the required configurations.

Comment: Put up some code, maybe there's something in there that isn't kosher.

Comment: phpmailer works on Windows platform https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer have you tried that?

Comment: Well Ellen; if you wish to contact anyone of us, use an `@` symbol followed by their name. I'm closing this tab and moving on. Good luck.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Thank you for your help. I have posted the test basic code that I am using. Because I cannot access the php.ini file (that I know of) I am trying to use the ini_set() functions

Comment: @Fred-ii- ^^ see above please

Comment: @EllenStuder Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is the error I received: Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.theinspros.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\HTTP\Old Web\version.php on line 9

Comment: @EllenStuder You may need to use a different port and use an SSL socket. Other available ports are 465 and 587, there's probably a few more. phpmailer may be a better program to use also. You will need to contact your hosting provider once again. There surely must be something that they can do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok thanks again for your help. Ill try these ports and contact the hosting provider again.